# Как лучше инициализировать постоянные переменные. Или хотя бы в чем разнице. скрин приложен

Tags: static

Картинка к сожалению не прикрепляется. поэтому тут придется написать..

```
public class Test {

//сразу после объявления
private static int cislo1 = 100;
private static int cislo2;
private static int cislo3;
private int nonStaticcislo;

//в конструкторе
public Test() {
    cislo2 = 200;
}

//в блоке инициализации статических переменных
static {
    cislo3 = 300;
}

//в блоке инициализации НЕ статических переменных
{
    neStaticСislo=9999;
}
```

}

Comment: Тебе просто невероятно повезло, что картинка не прикрепляется. А то вопрос бы закрыли, а тебя бы забанили :D

Comment: всм, почему????

Comment: потому что правила не читал.

Comment: постоянные переменные это топчик, примерно как альтернативные факты

Comment: Они так называются. То что ты привык к fields или поля. не значит что это их единственно-правильно название. еще чтобы ты знал они могут называться объектные переменные. умник